# box shadows behavior on adjacent box

Tags: css

I have three box and I created a shadow on mouse over with css

```
<div class='item-box'>
   <p>first</p>
</div>
<div class='item-box'>
   <p>second</p>
</div>
<div class='item-box'>
   <p>third</p>
</div>
```

css

```
.item-box {
   width: 700px;
   background: #fff;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}

.item-box:hover {
   border: 1px solid #999;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
   box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgmq7/)

I'd like the bottom shadow of the first box appeared above the second box (same thing with the second on the third) on mouseover. I've tried using z-index, but without success. How could I do this? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your CSS per the below- the crucial part here is using `z-index` to change the 'layering' of your items, putting the hovered item on top:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Tgmq7/1/)

```
.item-box {
    width: 700px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative; /* apply a position so z-index will work */
    z-index:0; /* set z-index to zero for all items */
}

.item-box:hover {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    z-index:1; /* set z-index to 1 for hovered item, so it appears on top*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried too z-index with no success, but I had not used position!